# Rails 4: Filter with tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, enums, inject

I followed a tutorial and created a tagging method on my recipe website.  I have the following models:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :taggings
    has_many :tags, through: :taggings
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :taggings
    has_many :recipes, through: :taggings
end

class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :recipe
end
```

In my recipe index I'd like to create a filter that selects for recipes that have **ALL** tags selected by the user.

I have a method of pulling all recipes with a given tag:

```
def self.tagged_with(name)
    Tag.find_by_name!(name).recipes
end
```

...and I'm trying to use `inject` to combine multiple tags into a single query:

```
def self.new_filter(tags) # tags is an array
    tags.inject(Recipe.all) { |res, arg| res.tagged_with(arg) }
end
```

But this does not return the recipes with all tags, it returns recipes with the final tag in the tags array.  How do I fix this to return only recipes with all tags?

Comment: This is a pretty similar question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17920505/match-all-in-active-record-relations-in-a-query which has an answer that can at least get you pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this `tags.inject(Recipe.all) { |res, arg| res.tagged_with(arg) }` line, The problem is you are returning the the `Recipies` after it fetches it with `tagged_with` method the operation ends there. So for every element of `tags` array the `inject` will perform the operation and return the result but won't pass it back for next iteration of `inject` operation on `tags`. At the end you will get whatever it will return after performs query for last tag.

you can do something like this:

```
def self.new_filter(tags) # tags is an array
  res = Recipe.all;
  tags.inject({}) { |all_res, arg| all_res[arg] = res.tagged_with(arg); all_res }
end
```

After this you will get a hash with key as tag name and recipes as values like:
`my_recipes = {:chinese => *all data returned for chinese*}`

OR you can do something like

```
def self.new_filter(tags) # tags is an array
 Recipe.joins(:tags).where('tags.name IN (?)', tags)
end
```

PS: I have not tested any code, do necessary adjustments if required