# Rails ActiveRecord query to match all params

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I need to have an ActiveRecord Postgres query that returns results which match all the parameters passed in through an array.

Some background: I have a User model, which has many Topics (through Specialties). I'm passing in the Topic ids as a string (`Parameters: {"topics"=>"1,8,3"}`) and then turning them into an array with `.split(',')` so I end up with `topic_params = ["1","8","3"]`.

Now I'm trying to return all Users who have Topics that match/include all of those. After following the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17920505/match-all-in-active-record-relations-in-a-query), I managed to return Users who match ANY of the Topics with this:

```
@users = User.includes(:topics, :organization).where(:topics => {:id => topic_params})
```

But I need it to return results that match ALL. I'd also be open to better ways to accomplish this sort of task overall.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636061/matching-all-values-in-in-clause

Comment: @Iceman, thanks for the link. How would I write that in ActiveRecord format in this instance?

Comment: ActiveRecord has `having` and `to_sql` methods to help you.

Comment: @muistooshort, thanks for the info. How would I utilize them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be something like this

```
User.joins(:topics).where(topics: { id: [1, 2, 3] }).group('users.id').having('count(distinct topics.id) = 3')
```

Obviously I haven't your exact schema so you might have to tweak it a bit, but this is the basic setup.

Important is that the having clause counter must match the number of items you're matching with.

Comment: How would I reflect that the number of items to match with is variable? Meaning that it can range from 1 up to ~10 (as opposed to being set at 3).

Comment: having('count(distinct topics.id) = ?', topic_params.split(',').count) or something like that

Comment: Alright. One more part of this: is there a way to eager load the other table(s), because I'd like to if possible.

Comment: Take a look at this http://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/07/01/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes.html